# WM_SETTEXT for STATIC text does not refresh the control content

Tags: winapi

This is curious for me.

When I use this:

```
Helpers.WinApi.SendMessage(nextControl, Helpers.WinApi.WM_SETTEXT, 0, "My String");
```

Where nextControl is a STATIC control (a label), the control does not refresh immediately. The curiosity is that the control shows the changed text only when I press the Alt key. It does not even show the changed text when I force the control refresh (for example, when minimizing and then restoring the window).

This only happen with STATIC control. With EDIT controls, it does not happen.

How to solve it?

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by changed the width of the label after set. This was necessary because if text is larger than the width of the label, it will be cut. As a side effect, luckyly, the static control was repainted, seeing the text set by the WM_SETTEXT message.

The code to enlarge the static control was:

```
                        // Si es un label, debe  agrandar el ancho para que se acomode a la cantidad de caracteres del control
                        System.Drawing.Size size = Helpers.WinApi.MeasureString(System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(hWnd).GetHdc(), formatted.ToString());
                        Helpers.WinApi.RECT rect = new Helpers.WinApi.RECT();
                        if (Helpers.WinApi.GetWindowRect(nextControl, out rect))
                            Helpers.WinApi.MoveWindow(nextControl, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left + size.Width, rect.Bottom - rect.Top, true);
```

Comment: You can use UpdateWindow() to get similar effect of forced window repaint.

Comment: @bunglehead I don't think so. When the whole window is repainted (because of maximizing or changing foreground window), UpdateWindow should be called automatically, and as I said in the question, Control refreshed only when i pressed Alt Key. Curious.

Comment: I mean UpdateWindow() on static control window itself of course, not your whole dialog or whatever parent this static has. Strange that I can't reproduce this with ControlSpy test program, both version 5 and 6 update immediately without forced update.

Answer (score 0):

One common cause of this happening is if the STATIC control has the SS_SIMPLE style. If you change the style to SS_LEFT for example, then redrawing upon text changing will occur correctly. (e.g. if the new text is shorter than the old text, you won't be left with residue characters to the right of the new text.)